# synchronizing only the assigning of a static variable

Tags: static, synchronized

I have a static variable which will be fetched a lot. I want to synchronize the initialization, but want it to be lazy loaded. So not making it final.

Is this a correct/acceptable approach ?

Here is the code.

```
public class Test {

    private static Object staticObj;

    public static Object getStaticObj() throws Exception{
        if(staticObj == null){
            assignNewStaticObj();
        }
        return staticObj;
    }

    private static  void assignNewStaticObj(){
        synchronized(staticObj){
            if (staticObj == null) {
                staticObj = new Object();
            }
        }
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can synchronize on something else that is `static`, cheap and not lazy:

```
public class Test {

  ...
  private static Object staticObjSync = new Object();

  ...

  private static void assignNewStaticObj() {
      synchronized(staticObjSync) { 

         ...
```